# MySQL query. Can I add a conditional in the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Basically, I am doing something like this:

```
select a.name from schedule as a
where date(now()) <= a.dateTo;
```

But `a.dateTo` can be null. So, I would like a query to do something like this:

```
select a.name from schedule as a
where date(now()) <= a.dateTo IF a.dateTo is not null;
```

That's just a simplified way to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The following example might give a better idea of what is required

```
select a.name from schedule as a
where date(now()) >= a.dateFrom and 
      date(now()) <= a.dateTo;
```

If I add the `OR a.dateTo is null`, I think it will override the first condition: `date(now()) >= a.dateFrom`, which is not the desired query. Something similar would happen with the use of `AND`.

If `a.dateTo` is null, it will be > date(now()), so those records should be retrieved, if the first condition also applies: `date(now()) >= a.dateFrom`

Thanks for your help

Comment: How should the rows where `a.dateTo` is `NULL` be treated?

Comment: How about replacing `IF` with `AND`?

Comment: Ive put an answer below, but a simple google search would give you the information for this

Comment: @nikc.org if a.date is null, those rows should be retrieved by the query. So, date(now()) will always be <= than a null value in a.dateTo

Comment: Errrrr, you can use brackets?  `(a < y OR a IS NULL) AND (b > z OR b IS NULL)`?

Comment: @AdrianBrown I would really appreciate if you could tell me what to search in google in order to get the accepted answer..... “Be silent, or say something better than silence”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.name from schedule as a where curdate() <= ifnull(a.dateTo,curdate());
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot for understanding and sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` and `or` logical operators:

```
where date(now()) <= a.dateTo
      OR a.dateTo is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive not tested it but something like

```
SELECT a.name FROM schedule as a WHERE (a.dateTo IS NOT NULL AND date(now()) <= a.dateTo)
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT a.name FROM schedule AS a WHERE date(NOW()) <= a.dateTo AND a.dateTo IS NOT NULL
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood how you want `NULL` values to behave, but perhaps this would work for you:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM schedule AS a
WHERE DATE(NOW()) >= a.dateFrom 
AND DATE(NOW()) <= COALESCE(a.dateTo, NOW());
```

But this is really the same as saying

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM schedule AS a
WHERE DATE(NOW()) >= a.dateFrom
AND (a.dateTo IS NULL OR DATE(NOW()) < a.dateTo)
```

Not sure which is more efficient.